# Terraform can't create free web app on azure

Tags: azure, terraform

Trying to setup my first web app using terraform on Azure using there freetier.

The Resource group, and app service plan were able to be created but the app creation gives an error that says:
`creating Linux Web App: (Site Name "testazurermjay" / Resource Group "test-resources"): web.AppsClient#C. Status=<nil> <nil>`

Here is the terraform `main.tf` file:

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "test" {
  name     = "test-resources"
  location = "Switzerland North"
}

resource "azurerm_service_plan" "test" {
  name                = "test"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.test.name
  location            = "UK South" #azurerm_resource_group.test.location 
  os_type             = "Linux"
  sku_name            = "F1"
}

resource "azurerm_linux_web_app" "test" {
  name                = "testazurermjay"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.test.name
  location            = azurerm_service_plan.test.location
  service_plan_id     = azurerm_service_plan.test.id

  site_config {}
}
```

At first I thought the `name` was the issue for the `azurerm_linux_web_app` so I changed it from `test` to `testazurermjay` however that was not able to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it to work **BUT** I had to use a `depreciated` resource called `azurerm_app_service` instead of `azurerm_linux_web_app`. I **ALSO** had to make sure that my `resource-group` and `app service plan` were in the same location. When I originally tried to set both the resource group and the app plan to `Switzerland North` it would give me an error when creating the app service plan (That is why you see me change the plan to `UK South` in the Original question). **HOWEVER** - after I set **BOTH** resource group and app service plan to `UK South` they were able to be created in the same location. Then I used `azurerm_app_service` to create a free tier service using the `use_32_bit_worker_process = true` variable in the `site_config` object.

Here is the full terraform file now:

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "test" {
  name     = "test-resources"
  location = "UK South"
}

resource "azurerm_service_plan" "test" {
  name                = "test"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.test.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.test.location 
  os_type             = "Linux"
  sku_name            = "F1"
}


resource "azurerm_app_service" "test" {
  name                = "sofcvlepsaipd"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.test.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.test.name
  app_service_plan_id = azurerm_service_plan.test.id

  site_config {
    use_32_bit_worker_process = true
  }
}
```

**I MUST STRESS THAT THIS ISN'T BEST PRACTICE AS THE azurerm_app_service IS GOING TO BE REMOVED IN THE NEXT VERSION. THIS SEEMS TO INDICATE THAT TERRAFORM WONT BE ABLE TO CREATE FREE TIER APP SERVICES IN THE NEXT UPDATE.**

If someone knows how to do this with `azurerm_linux_web_app` or knows a better approach to this let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered a similar issue, "always_on" setting defaults to `true`, but that is not supported in the free tier. As stated [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/linux_web_app#always_on), you must explicitly set it to false when using free tier

```
resource "azurerm_linux_web_app" "test" {
  name                = "testazurermjay"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.test.name
  location            = azurerm_service_plan.test.location
  service_plan_id     = azurerm_service_plan.test.id

  site_config {
    always_on = false
   }
}
```